# How to plot a product function in R?

Tags: r, plot, gamma-function

I'm trying a problem but first I have to plot in `r`

```
(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n),
```

with `n` being a fixed integer.

Any idea how to create this routine?

Comment: This is just $n$ times the fraction...

Comment: yeah, but is not easy to me in R

Comment: Well your question is not really clear. I got no idea what you actually want. Why is there no index $i$ in the formula?

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake , is 1/(x+i)

Answer (score 4):

Provided `x` is greater than -1, this might be most efficiently computed by exploiting the relationship

```
(x + 1)*(x + 2)* ... *(x + n) = Gamma(x+n+1) / Gamma(x+1).
```

Gammas are computed internally in terms of their logarithms, so use these logs in the form of `lgamma`:

```
f <- function(x, n) exp(lgamma(x+n+1) - lgamma(x+1))
```

A plot can then be obtained *via* `curve`, for instance, as in

```
curve(f(x,3), 0, pi)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this?

```
f <- function(x, n) {
  return(prod(1/(x+(1:n))))
}
```

Comment: That won't plot directly using `curve`, for instance, because it isn't vectorized.